# How to change default Nativescript opening page in Angular+Nativescript application?

Tags: android, image, nativescript, default, angular-nativescript

I am working on the Nativescript+Angular application and I am done with my assignment but now I want to change the default opening page image of NativeScript app.

I have tried but unable to find that. Please let me know if anyone knows.

Please see the image. I want to change this image.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the "Launch-Screen"? If so try to search for replacing the Launchscreen Image/Background

Comment: @Naxos84 Do you mean to say this "drawable/background"? I am not able to find any "Image/background".

Comment: For Android:  i.e. App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/background.png
Be aware to replace all resolution files.

For iOS the files are inside: App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets

Comment: For generating everything in the appropriate sizes you could use https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/resources/resources-generate-icons

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript Sidekick makes changing assets like this for iOS and Android a breeze.It will help you by generating assets like the splash screen or app icon from a single image for all the different required resolutions.

https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick

Answer (score 0):

What you see upon launch is called Launch Screen or Splash Screen.

The default configuration allows you to showcase a static image upon launch, you may update the images for iOS at `App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets` Or Android at `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-***/background.png`

On iOS, you may design your own customised launch screen if you are familiar with [Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html), the default story board file may be located at`App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

If you like some sort of animation upon launch screen, checkout [nativescript-splashscreen](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-splashscreen) plugin.